# ¿Cómo puedo poner un ciclo for en una clase que no es la main?

Tags: java, poo, bucle-for

Mi ejercicio es este "Una empresa almacena los datos de N empleados, para esto, en un proceso repetitivo se ingresa el sexo  y el  salario  de  cada  empleado.  Se  pide  calcular: a) El mayor y el menor salario b) El promedio de salarios. c) La cantidad de mujeres y varones que trabajan en esa empresa."

Yo ya lo resolví en una sola clase main:

```
public class Pregunta4 {



  public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N, i, m = 0, h = 0, sal, mayor = 0, menor = 9999999, cont=0, sexo;
        String nom, x = null;
        float prom=0;
        System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de empleados: ");
        N = scan.nextInt();

        for (i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
            System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del empleado: ");
            nom = scan.next();
            System.out.println("Ingrese el sexo del empleado " + i);
            System.out.println("1. Mujer");
            System.out.println("2. Hombre");
            sexo = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese el salario del empleado: ");
            sal = scan.nextInt();
            cont =cont+sal;

            switch (sexo) {
                case 1:
                    m++;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    h++;
            }

            if (sal > mayor) {
                mayor = sal;
                x = nom;
            }
            if (sal < menor) {
                menor = sal;
            }
            
            prom=cont/(m+h);
            
        }
        System.out.println("El total de varones es de: " + h);
        System.out.println("El total de mujeres es de: " + m);
        System.out.println("El mayor salario es de: " + mayor);
        System.out.println("El menor salario es de: " + menor);
        System.out.println("El promedio de salarios es de: " + prom);
    }

}
```

Pero ahora, lo que quiero hacer es hacerlo con dos clases, una main y una clase publica aparte, pero no se como trabajar con el ciclo for en una clase aparte, hasta ahora esto lo que voy de codigo:

```
//clase publica 

public class Clase4 {


 int sexo1(int sexo) {
        int m=0;
        if (sexo==1) {
                m++;
        }
        return m;
    }
    
    int sexo2(int sexo) {
        int h=0;
        if (sexo==2) {
                h++;
        }
        return h;
    }
    
    double mayor(double sal){
        double mayor=0;
        if (sal > mayor) {
                mayor = sal;
            }
        return mayor;
    }
    
    double menor(double sal){
        double menor=9999999;
        if (sal < menor) {
                menor = sal;
            }
        return menor;
    }
    
    double promedio(double sal, int h, int m){
        double prom, cont=0;
        cont =cont+sal;
        prom=cont/(m+h);
        return prom;
    }
    
    void mostrarResultado(int h, int m, double mayor, double menor, double prom){
        System.out.println("El total de varones es de: " + h);
        System.out.println("El total de mujeres es de: " + m);
        System.out.println("El mayor salario es de: " + mayor);
        System.out.println("El menor salario es de: " + menor);
        System.out.println("El promedio de salarios es de: " + prom);
    }
}

//clase main

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Pregunta4_1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N, i, sexo=0, cont=0, h, m;
        double mayor, menor, prom, sal=0;
        String nom;
        System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de empleados: ");
        N = scan.nextInt();
    
        for (i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
            System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del empleado: ");
            nom = scan.next();
            System.out.println("Ingrese el sexo del empleado " + i);
            System.out.println("1. Mujer");
            System.out.println("2. Hombre");
            sexo = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese el salario del empleado: ");
            sal = scan.nextInt();
        }
        
        Clase4 j = new Clase4();
        
        m=j.sexo1(sexo);
        h=j.sexo2(sexo);
        mayor=j.mayor(sal);
        menor=j.menor(sal);
        prom=j.promedio(sal, h, m);
        
        j.mostrarResultado(h, m, m, sexo, m);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: ¿Hay alguna razón por la que quieres trabajar de esa forma?, porque normalmente lo que deberías hacer es crear una **Clase** con los atributos (nombre,sexo,salario), dentro de esa clase o en otra clase puedes crear métodos que realicen lo que pides en a b y c.

Comment: La verdad no hay alguna razón en si, mas bien es la forma en la que por ahora estoy aprendiendo a trabajar, pero también estoy investigando formas mas sencillas de poder hacerlo, gracias por el comentario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cesar,

Es un ejercicio demasiado pequeño como para estructurarlo orientado a objetos, pero lo ideal sería que tuvieras una clase Empresa, otra clase Empleado, y otra clase Pruebas (donde pondrías el main).

Has revisado lo que hacen las funciones de sexo1()? Reciben un número y devuelven exactamente el mismo número, no hace nada :p.

Así lo he puesto, main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sexo=0;
    String nom;
    double sal;
    System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de empleados: ");
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    //Incializamos el objeto fuera del for para que solo tengamos una estancia 
    //(ya que solo la usamos para guardar datos)
    Clase4 j = new Clase4();
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        //recoger datos
        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del empleado: ");
        nom = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Ingrese el sexo del empleado " + i);
        System.out.println("1. Mujer");
        System.out.println("2. Hombre");
        sexo = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Ingrese el salario del empleado: ");
        sal = scan.nextInt();
        //guardamos el sexo para contar cuantos h o m hay
        j.sexo(sexo);
        //guarda el salario en la clase si es el mayor hasta ahora
        j.mayor(sal);
        //lo mismo pero con el menor (se podría hacer una función que calcule 
        //mayor y menor, sin necesidad de separar)
        j.menor(sal);
        //guardamos el salario para luego poder hacer la media 
        j.guardarSalario(sal);

    }
    //con todos los datos que hemos ido guardando, hacemos el cálculo
    j.calcularPromedio();
    //función que únicamente printa las variables y guardadas en la base
    j.mostrarResultado();
}
```

Y la otra clase

```
//variables de la clase 
private double mayor = 0;
private double menor = 999999;
private int mujeres = 0;
private int hombres = 0;
private double totalSalarios = 0;
private double promedio = 0;
    
//función que recoge el sexo y guarda en mujeres/hombres para llevar la cuenta
public void sexo(int sexo) {
    if (sexo == 1) {
        mujeres++;
    } else {
        hombres++;
    }
}

//función para saber si es el mayor salario hasta ahora
public void mayor(double salario) {
    if (salario > mayor) {
        mayor = salario;
    }
}

//función para ver si es el menor salario hasta ahora
public void menor(double sal) {
    if (sal < menor) {
        menor = sal;
    }
}

//va sumando salarios
public void guardarSalario(double salario) {
    totalSalarios+=salario;
}

//fórmula para devolver el promedio
public void calcularPromedio() {
    promedio = totalSalarios / (mujeres + hombres);
}

//printa las variables
public void mostrarResultado() {
    System.out.println("El total de varones es de: " + hombres);
    System.out.println("El total de mujeres es de: " + mujeres);
    System.out.println("El mayor salario es de: " + mayor);
    System.out.println("El menor salario es de: " + menor);
    System.out.println("El promedio de salarios es de: " + promedio);
}
```

Por último, como consejo, los nombres de las variables nunca hay que escribirlos empezando con mayúsculas, solo las clases. También pon nombres mas explicativos a las variables y clases, ya que en un futuro si vuelves a leer tu programa se te hará mucho más fácil de entender (sobre todo cuando trabajes con compañeros, agradecerás los que tengan nombres significativos).

Saludos

Comment: Hola, gracias, por tu respuesta y tus consejos, estoy aun aprendiendo este lenguaje, y pues estos ejercicios son los que me dan para practicar, pero agradezco tu ayuda y consejos, me servirán para desarrollar mas habilidades, buen día.

Comment: Un placer. Explicaría un poco más el ejercicio pero hay demasiadas cosas que mencionar, intentaré editar el código poniendo comentarios, si te sirven de algo

Answer (score 2):

He realizado algunas modificaciones en tu código para que sea más fácil, las clases quedan de la siguiente forma.

```
public class Clase4 {
  
  // se declaran las variables en la clase para que se puedan almacenar sus valores conforme se leen los valores.
  int hombres;
  int mujeres;
  double salarioMayor;
  double salarioMenor;
  double total;

  // un solo método recibe el sexo elegido y cuenta hombres o mujeres.
  void sexo(int sexo) {
    if (sexo == 1) {
      this.mujeres++;
    } else if(sexo == 2) {
      this.hombres++;
    }
  }
  
 // va guardando el salario
 void salario(double salario) {
   this.total += salario; // almacena la suma de los salarios.
 }

  // el método detecta si hay un nuevo salario mayor.
  void mayor(double salario ) {
    if (salario > this.salarioMayor) {
      this.salarioMayor = salario;
    }
  }

  // detecta si hay un nuevo salario menor.
  void menor(double salario) {
    if (this.salarioMenor == 0 || salario < this.salarioMenor) {
      this.salarioMenor = salario;
    }
  }
  
  // el método es privado porque se usa dentro de la misma clase, ya no recibe parametros porque la información ya se encuentra dentro de la clase.
  private double promedio() {
    return this.total / (this.hombres + this.mujeres);
  }

  // imprime los resultados, tampoco recibe parametros porque los datos ya están dentro de la clase. 
  void mostrarResultado(){
    System.out.println("El total de varones es de: " + this.hombres);
    System.out.println("El total de mujeres es de: " + this.mujeres);
    System.out.println("El mayor salario es de: " + this.salarioMayor);
    System.out.println("El menor salario es de: " + this.salarioMenor);
    System.out.println("El promedio de salarios es de: " + this.promedio());
  }
}
```

El main quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int N, salario;
    String nom;
    System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de empleados: ");
    N = scan.nextInt();
    Clase4 j = new Clase4();

    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
      System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del empleado: ");
      nom = scan.next();
      System.out.println("Ingrese el sexo del empleado " + i);
      System.out.println("1. Mujer");
      System.out.println("2. Hombre");
      j.sexo(scan.nextInt()); // se lee el sexo y se envía al método que cuenta hombres y mujeres.
      System.out.println("Ingrese el salario del empleado: ");
      salario = scan.nextInt();
      j.salario(salario);
      j.mayor(salario); // se envía el salario para saber si es menor.
      j.menor(salario); // se envía el salario para saber si es menor.
    }
    // una vez finalizado la lectura de los datos se imprime la información.
    j.mostrarResultado();
  }
```

Puedes probar el código [aquí](https://replit.com/@JoseManuel/Solucion-01).

Comment: Estaría bien que además de hacer cambios, le expliques el por qué de dichos cambios... **copiando y pegando NO se *aprende***. Como por ejemplo, por qué su método `int sexo()` no funcionaba y el tuyo `void sexo()` sí?

Comment: Gracias por la preocupación, pero no te preocupes, a mi no me gusta solo copiar y pegar, lo que hago es ver que cambios hizo analizarlos y entender por que los hizo, es obvio que es mas fácil si el pone la explicación, pero también me entretengo buscando la explicación yo solo, gracias.

Comment: //Comentario para la persona que escribió el código
Hola, gracias por tu ayuda, pero hay un problema, el promedio lo calcula mal, creo que es por la manera en la que se pide de que sexo es la persona, pero de todas formas, gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: @Benito-B en los métodos coloqué una pequeña descripción de los métodos.
Sus métodos sí funcionaban, pero comenté que los modifiqué para simplificar el código en el for.

Comment: @Cesar, tienes razón, he realizado los ajustes necesarios al código para que funcione correctamente, si tienes dudas no dudes en comentarlo.

Comment: Primero que nada, me alegro de que seas de los que no copian y pegan @Cesar, pero una respuesta sin explicación, es como media respuesta aquí en SO. Luego, @Freqde dices que sus métodos funcionaban... pues no lo creo ya que el `int sexo1()` no funciona correctamente, dado que usa una variable local en el propio método, así que siempre va a devolver 1 si cumple la condición, 0 si no! Recordar que aquí estamos para aprender, y una explicación siempre, SIEMPRE es bienvenida! Especialmente cuando estás respondiendo preguntas de gente que está aprendiendo. Un saludo :)